# Dynamically build json using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to dynamically build some json based on data I retrieve from a database.  Up until the opening '[' is the "root" I guess you could say.  The next parts with name and value are dynamic and will be based on the number of results I get from the db.  I query the db and then the idea was to iterate through the result adding to the json.  Can I use jsonBuilder for the root section and then loop with jsonSlurper to add each additional section?  Most of the examples I have seen deal with a root and then a one time "slurp" and then joining the two so wasn't sure if I should try a different method for looping and appending multiple sections.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    {
       "hostname": "$hostname",
       "path": "$path",
       "extPath": "$extPath",
       "appName": "$appName",
       "update": {"parameter":    [
                {
             "name": "$name",
             "value": "$value"
          },
                {
             "name": "$name",
             "value": "$value"
          }
       ]}
    }
```

**EDIT:** So what I ended up doing was just using StringBuilder to create the initial block and then append the subsequent sections.  Maybe not the most graceful way to do it, but it works!

```
    //Create the json string
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("""{
       "hostname": "$hostname",
       "path": "$path",
       "extPath": "$extPath",
       "appName": "$appName",
       "update": {"parameter":    ["""
    ) 


    //Append
    sql.eachRow("""<query>""",
    { params ->
    json.append("""{ "name": "params.name", "value": "params.value" },""");
    }
    ) 

    //Add closing json tags
    json.append("""]}}""")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got your explanation correctly and if the data is not very big (it can live in memory), I'd build a `Map` object (which is very easy to work with in groovy) and convert it to JSON afterwards. Something like this:

```
def data = [
    hostname: hostname,
    path: path,
    extPath: extPath,
    appName: appName,
    update: [parameter: []]
]

sql.eachRow(sqlStr) { row ->
  data.update.parameter << [name: row.name, value: row.value]
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Grails** and Groovy you can utilize `grails.converters.JSON`.

First, define a JSON named config:

```
JSON.createNamedConfig('person') {
    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) {
        Person person ->
        def output = [:]
        output['name'] = person.name
        output['address'] = person.address
        output['age'] = person.age
        output
    }
}
```

This will result in a statically defined named configuration for the Object type of person. Now, you can simply call:

```
JSON.use('person') {
    Person.findAll() as JSON
}
```

This will return every person in the database with their name, address and age all in one JSON request. I don't know if you're using grails as well in this situation though, for pure Groovy go with another answer here.